# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException this exception was throw

Tags: java, selenium

Actually, my code was correct but the element was hidden in the popup page. I can't handle a popup page to page down to show the hidden element. Can someone help to clear this exception? Like how to handle the popup page Scroll down?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The actual problem was need to scroll down a popup page, But I can't handle it. How do you handle a hidden division pop-up in Selenium?

Comment: You can use `Action Class` to move to the element and perform action, but this answer is same as you asked the question, it would be good, if you share the `HTML Source`, `Code` and `Error` to help you out clearly